# Where is the reply button in Google gmail (Chromebook)

Tags: google-chrome, gmail, user-interface

You'd think that in an email application the "reply" button would not only be visible but would stand out. I cannot find it in Google gmail on my Chromebook.

[image: Google gmail UI]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scroll down to the end of the message. That's where you will find the <kbd>Reply</kbd> and <kbd>Forward</kbd> buttons.

Answer (score -1):

As an alternative to the existing answer, one can press <kbd>R</kbd> to start writing a response. This avoid the potentially tedious scrolling down to the end of the thread.